# strripos returning first index instead of last index in php?

Tags: php, string, compare

I am performing this operation.

```
$title = "Group CIO, Member of the Executive Committee";

 $pos = strripos($title,"cio");
```

Instead of getting the `$pos` value as `8` I am getting `$pos` value as `6`. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `*pos*` functions that I know return the index at which the match *begins*. If you want to know where the match *ends*, just add the length of string and subtract 1:

```
$pos = strripos($title, "cio") + strlen("cio") - 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it's position is 6...

```
0123456
Group CIO, Member...
```

Answer (score 2):

> Find the numeric position of the last occurrence of needle in the haystack string.

The last occurrence is the second wod in your sentence which **begins** at position 6

Why did you expect position 8?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you expecting 8?

Let me demonstrate:

```
000000000011111111112
012345678901234567890
Group CIO, Member of ...
      ^
```

From [the manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php):

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
>   beginnning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1

Answer (score 2):

`strripos` finds the *first* character of the *last* occurence of the needle. You have to add the needle length manually

```
$pos = strripos($title,"cio")+strlen("cio")-1;
```